# Getting a little error with command

Tags: python

I have a plugin that runs in python for a game server of mine. I have an issue of getting the "error processing your command" in this part:

```
def cmd_cost(self, data, client=None, cmd=None):
""" 
^3<command> - Tells you the cost of the specified command.
"""        
input = self._adminPlugin.parseUserCmd(data)
weapon_cost = self._command_cost_dict.get('weapon',0)
item_cost = self._command_cost_dict.get('item',0)
if not data:
    client.message('^7 correct syntax is !cost [command]')
    return False
else:
    if  len([x for x in data if x.isspace()]) > 0:
        client.message('^7 correct syntax is !cost [command]')
        return False
    else:
        input_data = data.split(' ',1)
        command_name = input_data[0]
        if command_name in ['autobuy','buy']:
            client.message('^7Weapon cost: ^2$%s ^7Item cost: ^2$%s' % (weapon_cost, item_cost))

        if command_name not in self._command_cost_dict and not 'autobuy''buy':
            client.message('^7 This command needn\'t money or this command doesn\'t exist!')
            return False
        command_cost = self._command_cost_dict[command_name]
        if command_cost == 0:
            return False
        client.message('^7 Command %s needs ^2$%s' % (command_name, command_cost))
return True
```

This happens when they ask !cost [...] and it's not in the list. It should say "this command needn't money or this command doesnt exist" but it gives the error instead. Hopefully someone can help with that.
Thanks.

Comment: in this line `not 'autobuy''buy'` always evaluates to false

Comment: Will-hart, this should be an answer, not a comment, as it clearly answers the question.

Comment: @Apero - See below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in this line `not 'autobuy''buy'` always evaluates to `false`.

To fix this you could change the offending line from:

```
if command_name not in self._command_cost_dict and not 'autobuy''buy':
```

to:

```
elif command_name not in self._command_cost_dict:
```

This would only be executed if the command is not `autobuy` or `buy`.

Comment: Well since I can't vote yet thanks a lot. Worked like a charm :)

Comment: You can also click on the "tick" next to the voting section to mark this as the correct answer :) Glad it helped